# sqlalchemy tries to connect to mariadb using the mysql client library instead of the mariadb client library

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, mariadb

When connecting to a mariadb database with a command like this:

```
sqlalchemy.create_engine("mariadb://webuser:password@localhost/my_db")
```

I get an error like this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

it appears that sqlalchemy is trying to use `MySQLdb` to connect to a mariadb instance. Since I am using mariadb and not mysqldb I don't have the mysql client installed, and thus it's totally expected that the `MySQLdb` module is not available.

how do I make sqlalchemy use the mariadb client instead?

Answer (score 2):

sqlalchemy defaults to using the mysql client library to connect to mariadb instances.

To force it to use the mariadb client instead, add `+mariadbconnector` to your connection url like so:

```
mariadb+mariadbconnector://webuser:password@localhost/my_db
```